# Having trouble removing page numbers from ewic style class

Tags: page-numbering

I am using eWIC class for tex studio. Electronic Workshops in Computing (eWiC) Format. How does one remove the page numbers from the ewic class provided ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you add a pointer to the class and show a minimal example of code?

Comment: Do you want to remove all page-numbers at the bottom of the page?

Comment: hi greg the class is found here http://www.bcs.org/upload/cls/latex.cls that is the MEoC! @Christian - yes I want to remove them all but cant see where they are being written from

Comment: @StephenBradshaw: In line 232ff of the lines, page style is called `myewic`. I'll provide an answer in a few minutes. But please be aware, that the class has some copyright notes ;-) And the authors use a lot of deprecated commands :-(

Comment: @StephenBradshaw: If you can live without the running heads, `\pagestyle{empty}` is the easiest of all solutions, except for the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ewic.tex` file is taken as the sample file from http://ewic.bcs.org/content/conMediaFile/3029, the class can be found at the same page.

Page numbers enter the document usually via the pagestyle. There are two of them:

- `mytitle` for the titlepage
- `myewic` for the rest of the document.

I've copied the definitions of the pagestyles into `ewic.tex` and modified the relevant `\@oddfoot` macro, removing the `\thepage` formatting instruction there. Since `\@evenfoot` is a `\let` from `\@oddfoot`, this will change `\@evenfoot` too.

Please note the copyright issues here!

### There are a lot of deprecated commands as `\it` in the `.cls` file. The author(s) should revise the class!

```
% ewic.tex for classfile V2.04, 6 July 2011

\documentclass{ewic}
%\documentclass[cm]{ewic}

% http://ewic.bcs.org/category/15364


\makeatletter
\def\ps@mytitle{\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo%
\def\@oddfoot{\parbox[c]{\textwidth}{\small{\itshape%
\copyright\ The Authors.\ Published by BISL.}\phantom{\small\itshape \copyright\ The Authors.\ Published by BISL.}\\
\myfooter\mbox\hfill}}
% Original line
%\copyright\ The Authors.\ Published by BISL.}\hfill\thepage\hfill\phantom{\small\itshape \copyright\ The Authors.\ Published by BISL.}\\
%\myfooter\mbox\hfill}}
\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
\def\@oddhead{}
\let\@evenhead\@oddhead%
}

\def\ps@myewic{%
\let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo%
\def\@oddfoot{}
% Original code
%\def\@oddfoot{\small\mbox{}\hfill\thepage\hfill\mbox{}}
\let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot
\def\@evenhead{\parbox[c]{\textwidth}{\centering\small\itshape \rightmark \\\leftmark}}%
\def\@oddhead{\parbox[c]{\textwidth}{\centering\small\itshape \rightmark \\\leftmark}}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}



\runningheads{Smith $\bullet$ Doe}{A Demonstration of the \LaTeXe\
Class File for {eWiC}}
\pagestyle{myewic}

\conference{Proceedings of \dots}

\title{A Demonstration of the \LaTeXe\\
Class File for \emph{Electronic Workshops in~Computing}}

\authorone{Alistair Smith\\
Sunrise Setting Ltd\\
Torbay Innovation Center\\
Vantage Point, Long Road\\
Paignton, Devon, TQ4 7EJ\\
UK\\
www.sunrise-setting.co.uk\\
\email{alistair.smith@sunrise-setting.co.uk}}

\authortwo{John Doe\\
Sunrise Setting Ltd\\
Torbay Innovation Center\\
Vantage Point, Long Road\\
Paignton, Devon, TQ4 7EJ\\
UK\\
www.sunrise-setting.co.uk\\
\email{john.doe@sunrise-setting.co.uk}}

\begin{abstract}
This paper describes the use of the \LaTeXe\ ewic.cls class file
for setting papers for \emph{Electronic Workshops in Computing}.
\end{abstract}

\keywords{eWiC, \LaTeXe, Class file}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
This paper describes the ewic.cls class file which can be used to
convert articles produced with other \LaTeXe\ class files into the
correct form for publication by \emph{Electronic Workshops in
Computing}.

The ewic.cls class file preserves much of the standard \LaTeXe\
interface so that any document which has been produced using the
standard \LaTeXe\ article style can easily be converted to work
with the ewic style. However, the width of text and typesize may
vary from that of \emph{article}; therefore \emph{line breaks will
change} and it is possible that computer listings and displayed
mathematics may need resetting.

In the following sections we describe how to lay out your code to
use ewic.cls to reproduce the typographical look required for
online publication. However, this short paper is not a guide to
using \LaTeXe\ and we would refer you to any of the many books
available (see, for example, \cite{Companion,KopkaDaly,Lamport}).

\subsection{eWiC: Information for Authors}
You should also consult \emph{eWiC: Information for Authors} (available
from the BCS website) for important instructions about submission,
style and preparation of your paper.

\section{Getting started}
Simply place ewic.cls and ewic.tex in your systems usual
directories and typeset using your \LaTeXe\ or pdf\LaTeX\ command.
The ewic class file should run on any standard \LaTeXe\
installation. If any of the fonts, style files or packages it
requires are missing from your installation, they can be found on
CTAN or the \emph{\TeX\ Live} CD-ROMs.

eWiC is published using sans serif fonts for the text, hence the
default setting of the class file is to use Helvetica which should
be easily accessible with most standard \LaTeXe\ installations.
However, should this cause problems with your system there is an
option to use Computer Modern sans serif fonts instead: see the
example header in the next section.

\section{The article header information}
The heading for any file using ewic.cls is like this:

\begin{verbatim}
\documentclass{ewic}
%\documentclass[cm]{ewic}

\begin{document}

\runningheads{<1st Author's surname
$\bullet$ 2nd Author's surname
$\bullet$ etc>}{<Your paper title>}

\conference{<Proceedings of \dots>}

\title{<Your Paper title>}

\authorone{<A. N. Author>\\
<A full postal address>\\
\email{<Your email address>}}

\authortwo{<A. N. Authortwo>\\
<A full postal address>\\
\email{<Your email address>}}
.
.
.
\begin{abstract}
<Abstract text>
\end{abstract}

\keywords{<list keywords>}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\end{verbatim}

\subsection{Notes}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Please separate multiple author surnames by a `\verb+$\bullet$+' within the
\verb+\runningheads{}{}+ command.

\pagebreak

\item The class file is set up to handle up to six authors, i.e., \verb+\authorone{}...\authorsix{}+.

\item Note that the required reference style is Harvard. ewic.cls
uses `natbib.sty' to achieve the desired output so you will need
to choose a natbib compatible .bst that gives Harvard style
output. `chicago.bst' would be a good choice.

\item Try to balance the columns on the final page when your paper is submitted.
\end{enumerate}

That really is all you should need to know to prepare your paper
using ewic.cls.

You do, of course, have the option to call in any of your
favourite packages for setting maths, graphics, computer listings,
etc.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem[Kopka and Daly(2004)]{KopkaDaly}
Kopka, H. and Daly, P.W.  (2004) \textit{A Guide to \LaTeXe:
Document Preparation for Beginners and Advanced Users} (4th~edn).
Addison-Wesley.

\bibitem[Lamport(1994)]{Lamport}
Lamport L. (1994) \textit{\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System}
(2nd~edn). Addison-Wesley.

\bibitem[Mittelbach and Goossens(2004)]{Companion}
Mittelbach, F. and Goossens, M., (2004) \textit{The \LaTeX\
Companion} (2nd~edn). Addison-Wesley.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @StephenBradshaw: Please update, I've forgotten to use `\pagestyle{myewic}` after the title.